# How to validate phone number using javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

While i type the phone number in a field after 5 digits put a hypen and continue the digits
after hypen. It allows only 10 digits and hypen.

```
Output : 90000-00000
```

Can any one help me how to fix the issue.

Thanks

Comment: See this link for phone number validation.change the regex accordingly http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php

Answer (score 0):

The ReGex for this is really simple, you should have been able to Google this and work it out for yourself. The RegEx you want is as follows:

```
^[\d]{5}-[\d]{5}$
```

Using that with javascript:

```
var input = "90000-00000";
var valid = /^[\d]{5}-[\d]{5}$/.test(input);
//valid is a boolean: true or false
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TsbfX/)